# The question marked as duplicate. But where is the original question?

Tags: discussion, support, bug, duplicate-questions

I'm reffering to the question

[Why must a Java file have the same name as its public class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10442758/why-must-a-java-file-have-the-same-name-as-its-public-class)

The question marked as duplicate. But where is the original question ??

I'm unable to find the original question on that page. Is it a bug or feature ?

Answer (score 4):

The message got [edited out](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/10442758/revisions) cause the original dupe [was deleted](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2134784/458741). Yes, the duplicate message used to be embedded in the question.

Either

- the original dupe should be undeleted
- an alternative dupe should be found
- the question should be reopened
- the question should be reopened and closed for a more appropriate reason

Comment: You forgot "- the question should be deleted too". Not yet advocating either disposition.